# How can I reduce or disable enemy respawns?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Is there a way to reduce or disable enemies' respawn in DA Inquisition? (PC version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you complete certain quests in an area, the respawn of associated enemies drops considerably.

For example, in the Hinterlands, once you clear the mages' encampment, you no longer encounter mages, and once you clear the templars' encampment, you stop encountering templars. In the Hissing Wastes, there are only a few venatori camps that keep respawning after you destroy the main camp. Etc.

Answer (score -1):

Enemies do sometimes respawn in the middle of your party. The worst is when you kill an enemy and it respawns immediately! This happens quite often in some playthroughs and almost never in others. It is impossible to win a battle with even weak opponents when they respawn as fast as you can kill them. Only option is start a new playthrough.